# Native application to query ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana to process, store and visualize my logs. 
My setup works fine but now I'm looking for a new tool : before ELK I was used to read my logs on Notepad++ or Glogg (I'm on Windows) and now I'm using only kibana discover tab.

Do you think I can find a native application that looks like a read-only Notepad++ that query Elasticsearch and display my logs like before ?

The three features I actually need are :

- querying multiple sources logs,
- for a specified date range,
- and display it quickly to a concise and fast viewer.

I don't think it's very complicated to implement, so that's why i'm wondering if it already exists :)

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/275) for Kibana might be what you are looking for but there might be some time before it's actually implemented.

Comment: Not really, i'm just looking for something like the discover tab but faster and more compact. I'll work on my own implementation then, I'll push it to Github when it will be finished enough. Thanks